# Powershell : Executing custom function on remote servers

Tags: powershell

i have custom functions list, and another config file that is going to be used by the functions, my goal is to run those functions on remote servers, considering that some functions call other function from within them that's why i can't use the method below to call functions that are loaded in the local session.

```
invoke-command -scriptblock ${function:foo}
```

is it possible to make a module out of it and then make that module get imported automatically on system boot rather than user logon.
any suggestions on how to accomplish the main goal ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878340(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: i have thought about using modules. but how can i make the modules get imported automatically on system boot and not on user logon because i am not using PSSessions i am using invoke-command function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to install Powershell Module on the system just copy it to appropriate directory.

Installing Modules for all Users in Program Files
If you want a module to be available to all user accounts on the computer, install the module in the Program Files location.

```
$EnvProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\<Module Folder>\<Module Files>
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx

Install Modules in `PSModulePath` whenever possible, install all modules in a path that is listed in the PSModulePath environment variable or add the module path to the `PSModulePath` environment variable value.
The `PSModulePath` environment variable (`$Env:PSModulePath`) contains the locations of Windows PowerShell modules. Cmdlets rely on the value of this environment variable to find modules.
By default, the `PSModulePath` environment variable value contains the following system and user module directories, but you can add to and edit the value.

```
$PSHome\Modules (%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules)
# This location is reserved for modules that ship with Windows. Do not install modules to this location.
$Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules (%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules)
$Env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules (%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules)
```

Comment: will powershell automatically import that module once i call a function that's inside the module ?